# FadeIn/FadeOut Toggle Using One Button

Tags: jquery, button

I am currently using this code to try and use a button with a class of `.info` as a toggle for fading in and fading out text. Right now the animation is running back to back with this code. Is there a way where I click the button once and have the text fade in without it fading out seconds later? The same will apply for fading out when you click the button again.

```
$('.info').click(function() {
    $('h7').fadeIn(750);
});

$('.info').click(function() {
    $('h7').fadeOut(750);
});
```

Comment: [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) is a good place to start on this and probably [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) as well

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had to use if/else loop for this but this is so much more simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

```
$('.info').click(function() {
    $('h7').fadeToggle(750);
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you! I didn't even know this existed. Thank you again!

Answer (score 5):

```
$('info').click(function(){
    $('h7').fadeToggle(750);
});
```